# Floating divs contents to the bottom of the div. Sticking all content to bottom of surrounding div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position the second image inline next to the one before, the second image is smaller and i want it to sit on the same bottom line next to the larger one next to it. this will create a gap above the second image where i can put a small bit of text.

My problem is when i play around with background-size:, height: and width: to change the size of the image it just goes to the top left hand corner of its surrounding div.

I plan on having 4 more small image next to the small one so I'm asking please could anyone sort out the positioning of the divs and css so that i can easily add more next to the prior one,

Here is an image to give you an understanding of what i am trying to achieve, The red box shows where i want it to be positioned, and the other red box is where i will have the next skin.

**[LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrbSS.jpg)**

Things i have tried:

```
Bottom:0
```

`margin-top` ( to push it down ) though this does not leave room for me to add text above     the smaller images

```
padding-top:
```

Here is my current CSS:

```
#secondinner {
width:980px;
margin:0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
}

#dailyskin {
width:120px;
height:20px;
background-color:#336699;
color:white;
font-size:14px;
text-align:center;
padding-top:1px;
}


#topskin {
background-image:url(images/topskins/1f.png);
background-size:110px;
height:220px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:110px;
dislpay:inline-block;
float:left;
margin-top:5px;

}

#topskin2 {
background-image:url(images/topskins/1f.png);
background-size:80px;
height:150px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:80px;
dislpay:inline-block;
float:left;
margin-top:5px;


}

#downloadbutton1 {
width:100%;
}

#firstskin {
width:110px;
overflow:hidden;
float:left;
}
#secondskin {
width:100px;
overflow:hidden;
float:left;
padding-left:10px;

}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="secondinner">
<div id="dailyskin">Todays Daily Skin!</div>

<div id="firstskin">
    <div id="topskin"></div>
    <a href="images/skins/1.png"><button id="downloadbutton1" type = "button" name = "Download"> Download </button></a>
</div>

<div id="secondskin">
    <div id="topskin2"></div>
    <a href="images/skins/1.png"><button id="downloadbutton1" type = "button" name =   "Download"> Download </button></a>
</div>

</div>

This is the third section to the index page.


</div>
```

Here is a JS fiddle to show you what i mean,

http://jsfiddle.net/bjbear123/qdwgpaqc/

Comment: A jsfiddle.net would be very helpful :)

Comment: Okay ill put one together now, Thanks

Comment: Here is the  Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bjbear123/qdwgpaqc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: table-cell;` with a `vertical-align: bottom` could be a good solution.

[Have a jsBin!](http://jsbin.com/goquc/2/edit)

HTML

```
<div class="skin-wrap">
    <div>
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100X300" />
        <button>Download</button>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>text above </p>
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100X200" />
        <button>Download</button>
    </div>      
</div>

This is the third section to the index page.
```

CSS

```
.skin-wrap { 
    display: table;
}
.skin-wrap > div { 
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Also, to make it clear, you should be using `<img>`s and not CSS background images. An `<img>` is for content - which these clearly are, they're the whole focus of your page :) - background images in CSS are for decorative purposes.

Answer (score 1):

And if you don't want / are not able to use table-cell as misterManSam answered you can use nested divs with position absolute.

```
.wrapper{
position: relative;
height: 200px;
width: 100px;
}

.content{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
}

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <img src="whatever.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And there you have a little jsbin http://jsbin.com/jiqakefu/1/

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution is to increase the top margin of topskin2.

```
#topskin2 {
background-image:url(images/topskins/1f.png);
background-size:80px;
height:150px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:80px;
dislpay:inline-block;
float:left;
margin-top:75px;
```

i tried this on jsfiddle both download button were inline.
You can set margin as per your need, if you want space between both then you can use margin-left to create gap.

Answer (score 0):

you were right doing it through `bottom:0;`
The thing you missed was to set `position:absolute;` and for outer div `position:relative;`

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nive00/qdwgpaqc/2/